# Why doesn't Java allow child object creation from parent constructor

Tags: java

```
class Human{
    public void eat()
    {
        System.out.println("Human is eating");
    }
}
class Boy extends Human{
    public void eat(){
        System.out.println("Boy is eating");
    }
    public static void main( String args[]) {
        Boy obj1 = new Human();
        //Here it shows incompatible types
    }
}
```

I am new to java - could anyone let me know why the above object creation of a child class is not possible when using the parent constructor?

Comment: Every Orange is a fruit but not every fruit is Orange.

Comment: Ok here is the reason for down votes if you are wondering. This question is better candidate for Google and not for SO.

Comment: It doesn't allow it, because its wrong. Your expectation is invalid.

Comment: @ANS awsome. 
Now please provide some technical clarification.

Comment: You're creating a Human, but calling it a Boy.  What should the code do if a method in Boy is called that doesn't exist in Human?  (FWIW IMHO this is a perfectly valid SO question).

Comment: @ANS Not really google. More like "101 of inheritance". Thats like an absolute basic thing. In other words: you do some study/research.

Comment: @DeekshaAggarwal My first comment is indirectly an answer where Fruit = Human and Boy = Orange.

Comment: @DeekshaAggarwal You already got that. Inheritance means A IS-A B. You are creating a HUMAN and expect that to be a BOY.

Comment: Still not able to get the insight, every child has the properties of parent, why an object of child can not be created by parent constructor.

Comment: lets image your Boy class would have a method "showMaleGenitals()" that your Human class has not. If you were able to create a Human but declare it as a Boy and call obj.showMaleGenitals() what method should be called? Because the actual Human object doesn't have that method. "every child has the properties of parent" <- it might have more, thats the problem here. You cannot say you want to create a boy and then create an object that might be missing a lot of what the boy class actually defines.

Comment: When you ask why, do you mean “tell me the rule that says it’s forbidden” or do you mean “why did they invent such a rule?”?

Comment: @OH GOD SPIDERS, what if human has the method showMaleGenitals() also which is in child class as well.

Comment: Who cares. The point is that it **could** have have more methods,  fields etc.

Comment: Wow, now if i am not getting the logical answer and i know you got frustrated you guys will use your repo to get down my reputation score.

Comment: (1) They made a simple rule; you may argue it forbids corner cases that might have been useful, but in the big picture it’s still preferable to a more complicated rule that says “if there are no extra methods …” (2) If your code was valid now and someone later added a method to `Boy`, then your old code would probably get invalid. What a mess.

Comment: I was watching durga soft tutorial on you tube and he had the session for this and my bad luck was my internet data got finished. No problem i will find the answer their

Comment: BTW, your `Boy` class already has an extra method. The method call `obj1.main(new String[0])` is perfectly valid in your program, but the `Human` class doesn’t have a `main` method that could be called.

Comment: I am able to understand it generically. But what happens internally. It shows incompatible types for Boy obj = new Human(); in IDE.
@Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case Boy **IS-A** Human, so you can create Human, with Boy's constructor. But since (as per OOP) Human **is not a** Boy, thus you cannot create Boy's instance calling the Human's constructor.
So you cannot create a child instance directly using the super or parent constructor.
Boy boy = new Human(); NOT POSSIBLE
Human hm = new Boy(); POSSIBLE