# Type Mismatch Error when creating Object

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

When I created an object for subClass by Super Class as a reference Variable.
eg:

```
 class A {  
    A() { }  
 }  

 class B extends A {  
    B() { }  

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
       A a = new B(); // Compiles and runs
       B a = new A(); // Does not compile - "Type mismatch" error
    }  
 }
```

If I have there `A a = new B();`, it compiles and works. If I replace it with with `B a = new A();` I get a "Type mismatch" error.

Why?

Comment: `A a = new B();` is polymorphism because `A` is the parent of `B`, but `B` isn't the parent of `A`...

Comment: Because all `B` is an `A` but not vice versa. Replace 'A' by 'Animal' and 'B' by 'Bird'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't Java allow child object creation from parent constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43044548/why-doesnt-java-allow-child-object-creation-from-parent-constructor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that the class `B` is more specific than the class `A` and the constructor for the class `A` creates only the stuff from class `A`.

Replace `A` with `Animal` and replace `B` with `Baboon`. Every [baboon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baboon) is an animal, but [not every animal is a baboon](http://www.skyenimals.com/alph_index.cgi?letter=B). Now the following is perfectly OK:

```
Animal a = new Baboon();
```

And what you are trying to do is

```
Baboon a = new Animal();
```

So the compiler is unhappy, because your wife sent you to buy a baboon and you are bringing her a generic animal (maybe a basilisk?) :)